# In R - Using gt() and gtExtras() tables packages is possible to create expandable row?

Tags: r, gt, reactable, reactablefmtr

Is it possible to include a expandable row in `gt()`/`gtExtras()` packages in R, just like we can create in `reactable()` package?

https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#expandable-row-details

This is my code:

```
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)   
library(htlmtools)
mtcars %>% select(cyl,mpg) %>% gt()
```

I woudl like to include `h1("Title")` tag inside a expandable row.

Any help?

Comment: @akrun thanks for your time. Yes, I am working with gt package and It would be amazing to have this kind of effect.

Comment: I've been using gt package quite sometimes now 
can you produce a sample of what or how you want the result to look like.

Comment: @user16087142 I just updated with a example from `reactable()`package